# PHP change Color CSS

Tags: php, css

I have a problem with one element on my website which stays black.
I think it has no own CSS Class.

Heres the code:

```css
$search_output .= '<input type="text" placeholder="'.__("Search", "swiftframework").'" name="s" autocomplete="off" /></form><div class="ajax-search-results"></div></div>'. "\n";
    $search_output .= '</li>'. "\n";
```

There is a placeholder with the word "Search" which is automatically black.
How can  I change the color to white directly in the code or maybe
with an CSS Class in the custom CSS.

Tanks for your help.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=css+placeholder+text+colour&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&oq=css+placeholder+text+colour&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.5503j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Why did you tagged this question as PHP? It looks like it's a HTML/CSS question.

Answer (score 1):

To change placeholder text color, you can add a class to input and apply these styles on that class e.g `class="white-input"`

```
.white-input::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
    color: white;
    opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}

.white-input:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
    color: white;
}

.white-input::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
    color: white;
}
```

The additional code is for browser compatibility.
If you want to change every input's placeholder color you can use these without class scope:

```
::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
    color: white;
    opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
    color: white;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
    color: red;
}
```

For further details visit https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_placeholder.asp

Answer (score 0):

In most browsers, the placeholder text is grey. To change this, style the placeholder with the non-standard ::placeholder selector. Note that Firefox adds a lower opacity to the placeholder, so we use opacity: 1 to fix this.

```css
 ::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
        color: red;
        opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
    }
    
    :-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
        color: red;
    }
    
    ::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
        color: red;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
```

source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_placeholder.asp

Answer (score 0):

Please add this css:

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: red;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: red;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: red;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
```

You can replace red with what colour code you need.